# C++ iterator over grapheme clusters

Tags: c++, unicode

I have an iterator for iterating over unicode codepoints (elements are not kept in contiguous memory). I need an iterator adaptor which would allow me to iterate over grapheme clusters. Does anyone know any library which offers exactly what I need?

I've checked ICU already but its interface forces me to copy the whole range into the UnicodeString/UText.

Comment: The Courier unicode library implements [unicode_grapheme_break](http://www.courier-mta.org/unicode/unicode_grapheme_break.html)() that indicates whether two consecutive unicode characters form a grapheme break. Using that, it should be possible to implement an iterator over the individual graphemes.

Comment: Looks promising. Is the break point always possible to determine by looking at the two consecutive characters?

Comment: According to my read of [TR29](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/tr29-27.html#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundary_Rules), yes. And unicode_grapheme break is, pretty much a [direct implementation of that ruleset](https://github.com/svarshavchik/courier-libs/blob/master/unicode/unicode_graphemebreak.c).

Comment: I wrote my own implementation here https://github.com/rmartinho/ogonek/blob/devel/include/ogonek/segmentation/detail/grapheme_iterator.h%2B%2B but it is a work in progress; feel free to steal ideas from there, but don't take as production-ready. I also know that Boost.Locale has some iterators that do this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/locale/doc/html/index.html

Comment: dead link  xxxxx